# Getting 403 forbidden when accessing any endpoint

Tags: java, spring, http, security

my problem is with getting 403 forbidden response when trying to access any endpoint with login and password from user via postman. I don't know what am I doing wrong, even when I change access to permitAll() for each endpoint and don't use aneRquest.authenticated()?  What is wrong, what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

EventHandler class (giving user a role when creating him)

````
@RepositoryEventHandler
@CommonsLog
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler {

    private final RoleEntityRepository roleRepository;

    private final AvailabilityRepository availabilityRepository;

    @HandleAfterCreate
    public void handleAbsenceBeforeCreate(Absence absence) {
        log.info("creating Absence entity");
        if (availabilityRepository.findAll().isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        availabilityRepository.deleteAll(availabilityRepository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getStartTime().equals(
                        absence.getAbsenceStart())
                        && e.getEndTime().equals(absence.getAbsenceEnd())
                        && e.getBarber().equals(absence.getBarber())
                        && e.getWorkDay().equals(absence.getWorkDay()))
                .toList());
        ;
    }

    @HandleBeforeDelete
    public void handleAbsenceBeforeDelete(Absence absence) {
        log.info("deleting Absence entity");
        var availability = Availability.builder()
                .barber(absence.getBarber())
                .workDay(absence.getWorkDay())
                .endTime(absence.getAbsenceEnd())
                .startTime(absence.getAbsenceStart())
                .build();
        availabilityRepository.save(availability);
    }

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleUserBeforeCreate(User user) {
        log.info("assigning default role to new User entity");
        if (roleRepository.existsByName(Role.USER)) {
            user.setRoles(List.of(roleRepository.findByName(Role.USER)));
        } else {
            user.setRoles(List.of(RoleEntity.builder().name(Role.USER).build()));
        }
    }
}

```

userService class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND = "user with login %s not found";

    private final AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler repositoryEventHandler;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;


    @Override
    public List<UserDto> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(userMapper::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto createUser(CreateUserDto createDto) {
        User user = userMapper.toNewEntity(createDto);
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            throw new UniqueValueException(ExceptionMessages.EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_EXIST.getMessage());
        } else if (userRepository.existsByLogin(user.getLogin())) {
            throw new UniqueValueException(ExceptionMessages.LOGIN_IS_ALREADY_EXIST.getMessage());
        }
        repositoryEventHandler.handleUserBeforeCreate(user);
        return userMapper.toDto(userRepository.save(user));
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto updateUser(UserDto userDto) {
        return userRepository.findById(userDto.getId()).map(user -> {
            user.setName(userDto.getName());
            user.setSurname(userDto.getSurname());
            user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
            user.setPhoneNumber(userDto.getPhoneNumber());
            return userMapper.toDto(user);
        }).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteUserById(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByLogin(login).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(
                String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND, login)));
        //return User.build(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto getCurrentUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String login = auth.getName();
        List<UserDto> users = userRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(userMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return findCurrentUser(login, users);
    }

    public UserDto findCurrentUser(String login, List<UserDto> users) {
        List<UserDto> currentUser = new ArrayList<>();
        users.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getLogin().equals(login))
                .forEach(currentUser::add);
        return currentUser.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto getLoggedInUser() {
        var user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return userMapper.toDto(user);
    }
}
```


User class
```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(unique = true, name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(unique = true, name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<RoleEntity> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream().map(e -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(e.getName().name())).toList();
    }

//    public static User build(User user) {
//        return new User(user.getId(), user.getName(), user.getSurname(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()
//                , user.getEmail(), user.getPhoneNumber(), user.getRoles(), user.getAppointments());//getRoles na getAuthorities()
//    }


    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;

    }
}
```


UseServiceImpl class
```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND = "user with login %s not found";

    private final AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler repositoryEventHandler;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;


    @Override
    public List<UserDto> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(userMapper::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto createUser(CreateUserDto createDto) {
        User user = userMapper.toNewEntity(createDto);
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            throw new UniqueValueException(ExceptionMessages.EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_EXIST.getMessage());
        } else if (userRepository.existsByLogin(user.getLogin())) {
            throw new UniqueValueException(ExceptionMessages.LOGIN_IS_ALREADY_EXIST.getMessage());
        }
        repositoryEventHandler.handleUserBeforeCreate(user);
        return userMapper.toDto(userRepository.save(user));
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto updateUser(UserDto userDto) {
        return userRepository.findById(userDto.getId()).map(user -> {
            user.setName(userDto.getName());
            user.setSurname(userDto.getSurname());
            user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
            user.setPhoneNumber(userDto.getPhoneNumber());
            return userMapper.toDto(user);
        }).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteUserById(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByLogin(login).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(
                String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND, login)));
        //return User.build(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto getCurrentUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String login = auth.getName();
        List<UserDto> users = userRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(userMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return findCurrentUser(login, users);
    }

    public UserDto findCurrentUser(String login, List<UserDto> users) {
        List<UserDto> currentUser = new ArrayList<>();
        users.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getLogin().equals(login))
                .forEach(currentUser::add);
        return currentUser.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto getLoggedInUser() {
        var user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return userMapper.toDto(user);
    }
}
```


Security class
```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Security {

    private final UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity

                .authorizeHttpRequests((request) -> request
                       .requestMatchers( "/absence/**", "/barber/**", "/products/**",
                                "/appointment/**", "/workday/**", "/workyear/**", "/workdefinition/**","/user/create")
                      .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/absence/create", "/absence/get/barber").hasAuthority("ROLE_PERSONNEL")
                        .requestMatchers( "/user/delete/{id}", "/user/update",
                               "/products/get", "/barber/get", "/appointment/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/user/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin()
               .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000")
                .failureUrl("/http://localhost:3000:")
                .and()
               .logout().permitAll()
             .and()
             .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    // CZY POTRZEBNE???
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        authenticationManager.authenticate((Authentication) daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userServiceImpl);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Configuration class
```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConfigurationBeans {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler absenceRepositoryEventHandler(RoleEntityRepository roleRepository, AvailabilityRepository availabilityRepository) {
        return new AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler(roleRepository, availabilityRepository);
    }
}

```
````

Comment: In security chain the ```/user/login``` endpoint needs a role ```ROLE_USER```. So before you login you already have to be logged in and need a role. Login endpoint must be public.

Comment: @zforgo sorry, that was an old version of the code. Right now I have "user/login" in permitAl() and it still doesn't work